# Non-Responsive Site Breaking on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I'm trying to style a non-responsive site. It looks great on desktop. On iPhones, the content and text breaks and overlaps. I do not have a viewport set, so I assumed it would just look like the desktop version but "zoomed out" or "tiny"... I don't understand why this is happening. Please be gentle. I'm feeling pretty burnt out today ;)

Here is an example of my issue: [Desktop VS iPhone Example](https://cloudup.com/crB6CULTZ5c)

*Edit: ceejayoz answered this, for some reason I can't find the "answered" button.

Comment: Try `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` in your CSS. It's typically pretty good at picking a font size but I'd guess the boxes are absolute positioned.

Comment: YES! This fixed it! Can you explain your answer? Btw, I was able to upvote your answer but how to I accept this answer?

Comment: Added it as an answer (this was a comment). :-)

Comment: oh duh.. time for me to sleep now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile browsers adjust text size to make it a bit more readable.

Unfortunately, it looks like you're using absolute positioning in spots, so this very helpful feature is blowing up a bit.

Putting `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` in your CSS for those elements (or for the whole page, if you prefer) will prevent this automatic adjustment.